# ImportError: No module named controller.api python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In file `sched.py` I import `controller.api`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import controller.api
```

But python raises an error:

```
python sched.py                                                                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                           
  File "sched.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                       
    import controller.api
```

File `sched.py` is placed in the `controller` folder.

Inside `controller` I have file `api.py`

Why does Python gives me this error?

Comment: does the directory have `__init__.py` file ?

Comment: Directory where is placed `sched.py` contains `__init__.py`, but there is no this file where is `controller/api.py`

Comment: I had the same thought as YOLO.  If you do have a__init__.py file, then maybe you can show us the actual error.  I assume you're saying that you're getting "ImportError: No module named controller.api", but you don't say that explicitly.

Comment: Then that's your problem.  You need an \_\_init__.py" in the 'controller' directory

Comment: Why Python so heavy to use? (: Do you recommend to create __init__.py in each directories?

Comment: Yet if __init__.py will be empty?

Comment: yes, it can be empty.  That file defines a python module.  The code in that file will be executed when you import it, so there's lots of stuff you can do in that file to adjust your namespace, import other files, etc.  But an empty file is quite common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place an empty file named __init__.py in your 'controller' directory.  This file denotes that directory as being a Python module.  See:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

In my case (using PyCharm) I renamed the file and for some reason was throwing the 'No Module Name' error although I renamed it with the same name specified in my openapi file. Deleting and creating the file again with the correct name fixed the error